# jQuery Validate and ajaxSubmit not working with IE8, IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate, jquery-forms-plugin

I have the following form which works in IE7 and all Safari, Chrome, Firefox, but it won't work in IE8 and IE9. It correctly shows the success message but doesn't actually submit anything.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a solution for this?

Here is my form and script;

```
<div id="successMessage" style="display:none;"><p>Thank you for contacting Fussey Engineering. We will contact you within 2 business days.</p></div>

<form method="post" action="" id="contactform">

<label for=name accesskey=U><span class="required">*</span> Your Name</label>
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" value="" />

<br />
<label for=email accesskey=E><span class="required">*</span> Email</label>
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" value="" />

<br />
<label for=phone accesskey=P><span class="required">*</span> Phone Number</label>
<input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30" value="" />

<br />

<label for=comments accesskey=C><span class="required">*</span> Your Comments</label>
<textarea name="comments" cols="26" rows="8" id="comments"></textarea>

<hr />

<p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;"><span class="required">*</span>Are You Human?</p>

<label for=verify accesskey=V>3 + 1 =</label>
<input name="verify" type="text" id="verify" size="6" value="" />

<input name="contactus" type="submit" class="submit" id="contactus" value="Submit" />

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.validator.addMethod("verify", function (value, element, params) {
        return value == params[0] + params[1];
    }, jQuery.validator.format("Please enter the correct value for {0} + {1}"));

    $("#contactform").validate({

        success: function(label) {
                label.hide();
        },
        rules: {
            name: {required: true},
            email: {
              email: true,
              required: true
            },
            phone: {
              required: true,
              digits: true
            },
            comments: {required: true},
            verify:{
              verify:[3, 1]
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please tell us your Name",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            phone: "Please enter a valid phone number",
            comments: "Please enter your comments"
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $("#contactform").ajaxSubmit({
              success:function(e){
                $("#successMessage").show();
              }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: In your submitHandler, try returning `true` instead of `false`.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the suggestion. I re-tried in IE8 but it didn't seem to have an effect. :/

Comment: any errors in the developer console?

Comment: @cfs, Using `return false` as the last line within the `submitHandler` is perfectly acceptable.  It's supposed to block the regular `form` submit action when using `ajax`.

Comment: Have you done any basic troubleshooting to narrow it down to which plugin?  Use `console.log()` to verify that `submitHandler` is firing?  Assume the `submitHandler` is firing and that your problem is someplace within `.ajaxSubmit()`.  So my next question is, why not just use the jQuery `.ajax()` method within the `submitHandler` instead of another plugin?

Comment: I don't see where you're configuring `.ajaxSubmit()` so it knows where to send your data.

Comment: would I just replace the .ajaxSubmit with .ajax ?